# Clear text after onclick event and change image

Tags: javascript, html

I have a count down that launches after you click the button.  What I'd like to do is have the text and count disappear ("Starting counter here") after the count of 10 and then change the image from start32.png to stop32.png.

```js
var countdown;
var countdown_number;

function countdown_init() {
    countdown_number = 11;
    countdown_trigger();
}

function countdown_trigger() {
    if(countdown_number > 0) {
        countdown_number--;
        document.getElementById('countdown_text').innerHTML = countdown_number;
        if(countdown_number > 0) {
            countdown = setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', 1000);
        }
    }
}

function countdown_clear() {
    clearTimeout(countdown);
}
```

```html
<body>
<h2>My page</h2>
<table cellpadding="10">
<tr>
    <td>Click me</td>
    <td><img src = "dashboard/img/start32.png"
            title = "Click me"
            width = "32"
            height = "32"
            border = "0"
            onclick = "countdown_init()">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<p>Starting counter here:</p><div id="countdown_text"> </div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is an else statement and to set the images src. You can get the image by assigning it an id.

http://jsfiddle.net/6FF3V/1/

```
    if(countdown_number > 0) {
        countdown = setTimeout('countdown_trigger()', 1000);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('timer_image').src = "http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/19274250741916216090.png";
        document.getElementById('count_display').style.display = "none";
    }
```

Comment: Updated my answer - forgot that you wanted to hide text. Accomplish the same way, assign an id the elements and then set their display to none once the timer finishes.

Comment: I'm missing something here.  It is not working for me.  What are the divs I need to trigger the image change after the countdown?

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? Put a div around countdown with id of `count_display`. Then assign an id to img of `timer_image`.

Comment: Sigh...helps if I looked at the fiddle!  Thanks!  One more question: Is there a way I can have the text: "Starting counter here:" only appear with the countdown and disappear when the countdown is done?

Comment: Actually even further to that, is it possible to have an onclick event that will change the image back to the original?